# A player that adds video functionality to Win8 MediaElement control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

The windows 8 Metro XAML mediaelement is bare bones, and is essentially just a rendering surface.

Does any know of a good third party control which adds all the functionality you would expect on a video player? Such as play, pause, slider bar, full screen, etc? I'm looking for something akin to the HTML5 Video element that most browsers provide.

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement good control but some functions is restricted.
More enhanced control is "Player Framework".

By this control, can be played each encoded videos, playist, seekbar, pause, play, skin properties etc.

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/

[image]

Regards ;)